# How to create a pointy button?

Tags: android, xml

Asking some ideas, confuse where to start.

[image]

Comment: its a image not button

Comment: use the pre-drawn image for background

Comment: take a image and set it as background for button

Comment: **10** is a dynamic value, need to set also a value in it.

Answer (score 0):

For it you should have to make triangle shape using **XML**. 
Use Below link :
https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/android-triangle-arrow-defined-as-an-xml-shape/

Now, you have to place this triangle where you want.